# oracle online recovery does not change archived db

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, backup, recovery, rman

created db with dbca choosing asm, fast recovery area, archived mode.

Now I want to backup it preform some tests that would change the content of the db and If need comes then recover it from the backup. 
I know of export/import utilities but need to use rman in case I need to move the db.

I followed the following tutorial with some caveats with most of the commands succeeding:

https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/08/oracle-rman-backup/
https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/11/oracle-rman-restore/

```
RMAN> BACKUP DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG;
SQL> SHUTDOWN
RMAN> STARTUP NOMOUNT;
RMAN> RESTORE CONTROLFILE FROM "+DG1/<DB_NAME>/CONTROLFILE/CURRENT.<3_DIGIT_NUMBER>.<10_DIGIT_NUMBER>"
```

(before one of these commands) mounted the db with `SQL> STARTUP MOUNT` because needed exclusive type

```
RMAN> RESTORE DATABASE;
RMAN> RECOVER DATABASE;
RMAN> ALTER DATABASE OPEN RESETLOGS;
```

*last one didn't run successfully, outputted that only if badly recovered can be run

the change I've made to check the backup and recovery, was droping a table on one occurrence and inserting a record in another.
the problem is after checking the db didnt change to its previous state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"only if badly recovered can be run" is not a known error message.

NOthing changed, because you didn't put a limitation on the 'recover' step.  So it recovered right back through all the online redo - right back to where it was an instant before you shut it down to do the restore/recover.  You need to look at the SET UNTIL command in the rman manuals.  SET UNTIL a point in time or scn prior to when you did the activity that you expected to be gone after the restore/recover.

This is exactly as expected, and exactly what you would do in case of a disaster recovery where you do *not* want any data loss.  In your case you do not want complete recovery, but a Point In Time (PIT) recovery.

Comment: Also note that there is no need to specifically recover the control file, as it was not damaged or lost. A basic point-in-time recovery would work fine.